# angular 1 content update after search

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', []);

App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://api.com/&keywords=influence marketing")
  .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.influencers;
  });
});
```

So I have the code above loading the correct information for angular, but I want it so reload this with a new keyword param from a search form.

```
$( "#search" ).submit(function( event ) {
   // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();
  //$("#searchresults").empty();

  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
    terms = $form.find( "input[name='query']" ).val(),
    url = "http://api.com/&keywords=";


//output url+terms;

  });
```

Comment: Why do you mix jquery and angular? It would be way easier to do it in pure angular

Comment: what would be the best way to do this with angular?

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple way to do it all with angular.

you can notice the way I used $http

> params: $scope.form,

that will make sure that anything that's in `form` model will be sent as URL variables with GET request, so you can add as many inputs as you want and as long as the model will be `form.*` it will be posted

http://plnkr.co/edit/14e5852qLzethvZLXHG8?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.submitThisForm = function() {
    
    $http({
      url: 'api',
      params: $scope.form,
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
      //do some magic with response from server
    })
  }
  $scope.logToStackoverflow = function () {
    console.log($scope.form)
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitThisForm()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="form.query">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="form.whatever">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
    <input ng-click="logToStackoverflow ()" type="button" value="log output in stackoverflow" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```